# AWS Athena CTAS: Compacting parquet files and controlling block size (row grouping)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm looking to use AWS Athena to perform parquet compaction within my S3 datalake. Basically, I have many small files (e.g. 5-20 kb each) that I periodically wish to combine into larger files (e.g. 512 MB each). This can be done via below query:

```
CREATE TABLE database.new_table
    WITH (
        format = 'PARQUET',
        parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
        bucketed_by = ARRAY['my_column'], 
        bucket_count = 1
    ) AS
    SELECT * FROM database.original_table
```

My problem is that the resulting output parquet file does not use row grouping of any form. Below is a comparison of two ~50 MB parquet files - my original simulated file, and the one created by an Athena CTAS query (analysis output from MATLAB). Note that the files do not contain exactly the same #observations, which is as expected in this case.

```
>> parquetinfo("C:\Users\css\Downloads\00000000\00000000.parquet")

ans = 

  ParquetInfo with properties:

               Filename: "C:\Users\css\Downloads\00000000\00000000.parquet"
               FileSize: 56965797
           NumRowGroups: 3
        RowGroupHeights: [1000000 1000000 592000]
          VariableNames: ["t"    "a1"    "a2"]
          VariableTypes: ["datetime"    "double"    "double"]
    VariableCompression: ["snappy"    "snappy"    "snappy"]
       VariableEncoding: ["dictionary"    "dictionary"    "dictionary"]
                Version: "2.0"

>> parquetinfo("C:\Users\css\Downloads\00000000\00000000_athena.parquet")

ans = 

  ParquetInfo with properties:

               Filename: "C:\Users\css\Downloads\00000000\00000000_athena.parquet"
               FileSize: 58940690
           NumRowGroups: 1
        RowGroupHeights: 2591476
          VariableNames: ["t"    "a1"    "a2"]
          VariableTypes: ["datetime"    "double"    "double"]
    VariableCompression: ["snappy"    "snappy"    "snappy"]
       VariableEncoding: ["dictionary"    <missing>    <missing>]
                Version: "1.0"

>>
```

As evident, the file created by Athena has a number of differences (e.g. the version, variable encoding etc). But importantly, my original file is chunked into row groups as per the `RowGroupHeights` field. The Athena CTAS file has only 1 group, equal to the #observations in total.

The implication is that my queries are ~50% slower when run on the Athena CTAS output files (4 x 50 MB, 200 MB in total, calculating an average of a column across all data). If I use Athena CTAS to split the files into 11 files instead of 4, I get a result that is comparable on speed, which underscores that the issue on performance most likely relates to the lack of row grouping.

Is there a recommended work-around for this? I cannot see any options in the CTAS query statement to specify a block size or row grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We concluded that AWS Athena CTAS compaction was not ideal for our use case and instead went for date style partition projection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194112/sql-query-data-from-a-time-period-with-year-month-day-partitions)