# SQL: Query data from a time period with year/month/day partitions

Tags: sql, hive

I have an AWS S3 data lake of parquet files structured as below:

```
s3://bucket/device/table_x/year=2000/month=01/day=02/xyz.parquet
```

I'm aiming to use AWS Athena to query the data for display in Grafana dashboards. My challenge is that in order to create dynamic panels for any time period, while also leveraging my partitions, I need to find a way to restrict my data to the relevant time period in my `WHERE` section - but to do so in a way that will work across years, months and days - without having to construct the SQL statement depending on the query.

My best suggestion right now is below query, which should work - but it's convoluted. Is there a recommended best practice for such a statement?

```
SELECT
    Count(a1) as AVG_a1                 
FROM
    tbl_11111111_a
WHERE
    (
        -- Same year, same month
        (year = 'START_YEAR' AND month = 'START_MONTH' AND day BETWEEN 'START_DAY' AND 'END_DAY')
        OR
        -- Same year, different months
        (year = 'START_YEAR' AND month = 'START_MONTH' AND day >= 'START_DAY')
        OR
        (year = 'START_YEAR' AND month > 'START_MONTH' AND month < 'END_MONTH' AND day BETWEEN '01' AND '31')
        OR
        (year = 'START_YEAR' AND month = 'END_MONTH' AND day <= 'END_DAY')
        OR
        -- Different years
        (year > 'START_YEAR' AND year < 'END_YEAR')
        OR
        (year = 'END_YEAR' AND month < 'END_MONTH' AND day BETWEEN '01' AND '31')
        OR
        (year = 'END_YEAR' AND month = 'END_MONTH' AND day <= 'END_DAY')
    )
    AND
    t BETWEEN TIMESTAMP 'START_YEAR-START_MONTH-START_DAY 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP 'END_YEAR-END_MONTH-END_DAY 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What is the input to your query?  A pair of yyyy-mm-dd dates for start and end?  Or is it sometimes a pair of years, other times a pair of year+month tuples, and other times a pair of dates?

Comment: In Grafana queries, I would get a start timestamp and end timestamp. This can be 'split' into specifically the year, month and day of the start or end timestamp using Grafana's macro functionality. As such, my query can be used to leverage the start/end timestamp as a partitioning filter regardless of whether the period spans 1 day, multiple months or even multiple years. But my query remains rather convoluted, hence why I am looking to understand if there is an easier method. See also this one: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-athena-datasource/

Comment: It looks like the current query will have Jan 1st of this year match a range [Jan 2nd, Jan 3rd] of this year, only to be filtered out by the `t` clause.  Your OR condition sets need to be further grouped together, and additionally you need to apply those new groups only when needed (e.g., when START_YEAR = END_YEAR AND START_MO = END_MO for the first of them).

Comment: The intention is to use the year, month and day partitions to first select the relevant period at the 'day' level - then use the t (timestamp) to extract the exact period incl. HH:MM:SS. The motivation for this two-step approach is to leverage partitions to zoom in on relevant parts of the datalake, rather than trawl through all the data

Comment: Yes, that is clear — but your WHERE condition is inefficient, meaning the query will trawl through more data than it needs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the approach described in [this AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html) and [this blog article](https://tom-henderson.github.io/2021/06/27/athena-partition-projection.html).

Specifically, I setup my S3 structure as listed initially, except that I drop the hive notation (this could be retained, but I believe the projection date format becomes more messy in that case):

```
s3://bucket/device/table_x/2000/01/02/xyz.parquet
```

With this, I set up my table properties to use partition projection with below settings:

```
 "projection.enabled" = "true",
 "projection.date_created.type" = "date",
 "projection.date_created.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd",
 "projection.date_created.range" = "2000/01/01,NOW",
 "projection.date_created.interval" = "1",
 "projection.date_created.interval.unit" = "DAYS",
 "storage.location.template" = "s3://bucket/device/table_x/${date_created}/"
```

In my Table Schema, I update the JSON to the following:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "t",
    "Type": "timestamp",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "a1",
    "Type": "double",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "a2",
    "Type": "double",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "date_created",
    "Type": "string",
    "Comment": "",
    "PartitionKey": "Partition (0)"
  }
]
```

After making these updates, I can now query the data with the simpler partitioning structure proposed also by pilcrow:

```
SELECT
    Count(a1) as AVG_a1                 
FROM
    tbl_11111111_a
WHERE
    date_created BETWEEN '2000/01/01' AND '2000/01/02'
```

The point here is that I am able to retain a subfolder nested date structure (which I prefer for non-Athena datalake purposes - but still retain simple SQL query WHERE statements for my Athena queries, while using efficient partition projection.

Note also that I believe pilcrow is correct in analyzing that my original year/month/day SQL query had inefficiencies, as I found a 66% speed improvement when switching to the new structure for queries related to single-day 5 min intervals.

Comment: That’s a great resolution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

I see two options.

First, ideally, **repartition** to use a single "YYYYMMDD" attribute partition, rather than nested.  That's [a good practice for more natural querying](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Best-Pratices-for-Hive-Partitioning-especially-by-Date/m-p/112529/highlight/true#M75360), for example, "... WHERE ymd_partition BETWEEN 'START_YMD' AND 'END_YMD'", without all those boolean contortions.

Otherwise, continue with the current approach, which has a workable idea, but tighten it for **efficiency**.

We want to apply one and only one of the three scenarios (same yr/mo, same yr, different yr) based on the input range; however, as written, we evaluate each condition of each scenario against all records, regardless of input range.  (An input range of `[2023-01-31, 2023-02-1]`, for example, will inspect *every parquet file from January* because of the second-to-last OR condition, and thus mean we rely on the `t BETWEEN...` condition as an expensive backstop.)

The solution is not going to be pretty.

```
WHERE

-- apply only when input range has same year, same month
-- 
(start_yr = end_yr AND start_mo = end_mo
  AND "year" = start_yr
  AND "month" = start_mo
  AND "day" BETWEEN start_day AND end_day)

OR
-- apply only when input range same year, different months
--
(start_yr = end_yr AND start_mo != end_mo
  AND "year" = start_yr
  AND ( ("month" = start_mo AND "day" >= start_day)
          OR
        -- "day BETWEEN 1 AND 31" is superfluous here
        ("month" > start_mo AND "month" < end_mo)
          OR
        ("month" = end_mo AND "day" <= end_day) ) )

OR
-- apply only when input range has different years
--
(start_yr != end_yr
  AND
( ("year" = start_yr AND ( ("month" = start_mo AND "day" >= start_day)
                              OR
                           ("month" > start_mo) ) )
     OR
  ("year" > start_yr AND "year" < end_yr)
     OR
  ("year" = end_yr AND ( ("month" < end_mo )
                             OR
                         ("month" = end_mo AND "day" <= end_day) ) ) ) )
```

I probably missed a parenthesis in there.

You can add the `t BETWEEN` logic back on if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out! I'll get back once tested

Comment: One comment regarding the YYYYMMDD partitioning: This was my original structure, but my concern is that I'm setting this up with AWS Athena and using 'Partition Projection'. In such a scenario, AWS documentation warns that over partitioning should be avoided. To project an YYYYMMDD range, I would need to set the possible range from e.g. 20180101 to 20300101 in my use case, specifying the partition as an 'integer' indented by 1. The impact would be many 'wasted' possible partition outcomes, e.g. 20181301 etc. But I have not been able to find definitive conclusions for/against this.

Comment: I also saw this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html - it seems to indicate that I can use my existing structure, but change my partition projection to 'construct' a new partition, date, based on my year, month, day partitions (created by an AWS crawler), then I should be able to retain my S3 structure - but use the simpler partitioning query of the YYYMMDD format. But I'm not sure if I'm missing some important efficiency in doing so

Comment: @mfcss, interesting! I think you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> My best suggestion right now is below query, which should work - but it's convoluted. Is there a recommended best practice for such a statement?

I think you can also use the `CASE` expression to filter the data to the time period specified by the **START_YEAR**, **START_MONTH**, **START_DAY**, **END_YEAR**, **END_MONTH**, and **END_DAY** parameters.

```
SELECT
    Count(a1) as AVG_a1                 
FROM
    tbl_11111111_a
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN year = START_YEAR AND month = START_MONTH AND day BETWEEN START_DAY AND END_DAY THEN 1
        WHEN year = START_YEAR AND month = START_MONTH AND day >= START_DAY THEN 1
        WHEN year = START_YEAR AND month > START_MONTH AND month < END_MONTH AND day BETWEEN '01' AND '31' THEN 1
        WHEN year = START_YEAR AND month = END_MONTH AND day <= END_DAY THEN 1
        WHEN year > START_YEAR AND year < END_YEAR THEN 1
        WHEN year = END_YEAR AND month < END_MONTH AND day BETWEEN '01' AND '31' THEN 1
        WHEN year = END_YEAR AND month = END_MONTH AND day <= END_DAY THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
    AND
    t BETWEEN TIMESTAMP CONCAT(START_YEAR, '-', START_MONTH, '-', START_DAY, ' 00:00:00') AND TIMESTAMP CONCAT(END_YEAR, '-', END_MONTH, '-', END_DAY, ' 00:00:00')
```